# Facing issue when running the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Tags: php, xml, magento2.3.0, command-line, shell

Facing issue when running the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade

```
 The XML in file "D:/wamp64/www/porto/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/etc/communication.xml" is invalid:
Element 'topic', attribute 'is_synchronous': The attribute 'is_synchronous' is not allowed.
Line: 9

Element 'topic', attribute 'is_synchronous': The attribute 'is_synchronous' is not allowed.
Line: 12

Element 'topic', attribute 'is_synchronous': The attribute 'is_synchronous' is not allowed.
Line: 15

Verify the XML and try again.
```

Comment: did you changed any thing in core files?

Comment: no i just run command : composer update and after that i am facing that issue

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Let me know if you found something.

Comment: For some reason our file is out of date. Check this out https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Communication/etc/communication.xsd is_synchronous is there. And isn't on mine.

Comment: What is the final solution? I am also facing the same error.

Comment: whats the solution?

Comment: It did not work on my side to force source, as said in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24650 My final and only working solution was to remove the is_synchronous entries from the mentioned files.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up disabling these two modules, then setup:upgrade would get past the error.
bin/magento module:disable Magento_Amqp Magento_MysqlMq

Answer (score 0):

This Issue is Genuinly Due to Unknown Tag in Your

> D:/wamp64/www/porto/vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/etc/communication.xml

compare your file with

> D:/wamp64/www/porto/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Communication/etc/communication.xsd

`is_synchronous` attribute is used correctly or not

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a multiple PHP version, It could be the cause,

In this case, should check the CLI and Server version, these should be the same